# Trying to connect pi zero over USB

Tags: usb, jessie-lite, pi-zero

I have a pre-W Pi Zero.  I had it working as the wearable timelapse camera (Adafruit project). At this point I'm just trying to get into it via USB.  I'm also trying to do this on a defective Raspberry Pi Zero W in which the wi-fi doesn't work--not too worried about this but it would be great if that's its only problem and I can use it as if it were a non-W Pi Zero.

1. I start with SDFormatter
2. Then I put on 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie-lite
3. I added the ssh file
4. I added "dtoverlay=dwc2" to the last line of config.txt
5. I added "modules-load=dwc2,g-ether" after "rootwait" in cmdline.txt

   a) first I did this with wordpad in a windows 10 environment. It didn't work.

   b) I thought this (wordpad) might have been my error so I started over and made the above changes using a USB keyboard/HDMI/power and it still didn't work on USB after rebooting.
6. I did check, I do have bonjour on my laptop.

That's where I'm stuck.  I'm just not able to ping it or putty into raspberrypi.local.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that I could copy/paste into cmdline.txt using wordpad.  That worked for both pi zero's.  I was able to update/upgrade through my laptop's internet.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.